# Converting mobi files to pdf files

Tags: pdf, conversion, mobi

I have a Hanlin V3+ e-book, unfortunately it crashes too often when reading mobi files, so I want to convert them first into pdf, and then read pdf on V3+. Is there any tool for converting mobi files to pdf files? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) should do the job

You can right click on a book in your library, pick convert books - with options for individual or bulk conversion

[image]

Then on the next screen select your output format

[image]

Comment: Calibre looks better then many online services: at least it allowed me to change the page margins. However the way it rendered PDF makes me unhappy: the text line is split in the middle by page! Well, the line should either stay or go to next page... We're back to 80th.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this free [online service](http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf) to convert your mobi files to pdf.

Comment: That one failed to read mobi I have.

Answer (score 0):

[This site, called Docspal.com](https://www.docspal.com/), is the **bees knees** in online conversion. It also converts video to vid, pic to pic, doc to doc, audio to audio. It might even do video to audio (youtube, ha ha), but I haven't tested that one yet.